# Is length in FinFET changeable?

Tags: mosfet, finfet

I have a simple question. I need to make the PFET or PMOS FinFET weaker than minimum size when nfin=1. So Can I change its length from default  to l=2n in the netlist for simulation? It worked but I want to see if this is actually doable in fabrication.

Comment: Why don't you ask your FAB channel about DRC rules for your particular FinFET process? In general FETS length is always changeable to suite required driver strength, but in direction of longer FETS. Shorter FETS might be non-manufacturable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can layout transistor less than l=2n in CAD. With Finfets the length of transistor have quantized. So if you have to make PMOS weaker than NMOS, you need to use more fins for the NMOS.